# Replacing a string content using php, how to escape spaces?

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I don't really have an idea about this all i can think is regexes. This is what i really want to do. i have this html tag.

```
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="frenchnew.html" hreflang="fr" lang="fr" title="title">
```

i want to replace this whole sting into say:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="new.html" hreflang="ca" lang="ca" title="new">
```

i'm using `str_replace()` method. But the problem is what if search string has spaces between attributes like this: `type="text/html"<spance1><spance2><spance3>href="frenchnew.html"` how can i match when looking for the string? using regular expressions? i have no idea how to do that? Please help me out...

Answer (score 1):

You may do the 'pointed' replacements with replacement maps, like that:

```
$new_link = str_replace(
    array('="frenchnew.html"', '="fr"', ...),
    array('="new.html"', '="ca"', ...)
);
```

... so spacings won't matter at all, as they won't be changed.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i wanted to change the whole thing in once because there is a problem replacing using the method you mentioned. i'm reading a file here and replacing the content in that file. what if there was another sting similar to the search string `="frenchnew.html"` exist in somewhere else too? it will also be replaced ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Regular Expression that should work for your example regardless of the number of spaces between attributes.

```
$original_string = '<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="frenchnew.html" hreflang="fr" lang="fr" title="title">';
$pattern = '<link\s+rel="alternate"\s+type="text\/html"\s+href="frenchnew\.html"\s+hreflang="fr"\s+lang="fr"\s+title="title">';
$replacement = '<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="new.html" hreflang="ca" lang="ca" title="new">';

$new_string = preg_replace("/$pattern/", $replacement, $original_string); // Contains your new string
```